# how to properly secure access to a site

Tags: apache, security

I am a developer and have a site that has some sensitive information that needs to be online for people in different cities. The data is not of much use for most people (no CC numbers, or marketing plans)

the server has a LAMP stack.

I have used .htaccess on the server and the site has a web based sign in screen as well.

Two questions:
What is the best way to guarantee the data is secure (within reason)?
How can i check there has not been a security breach?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install SSL cert. and redirect all the HTTP calls to HTTPS (using .htaccess or httpd.conf).
2. There are many possible security breaches such as: code injection, sql injection etc. You can use services like [this](https://www.whitehatsec.com/seekinfo/GYRO/seccheck/SECURITYcheck.html?gclid=CMqh4PzryrACFWQKRQodmhR7XA) and [this](http://www.websitedefender.com/?gclid=CJD-iv7ryrACFYcZQgodXiq5WA) in order to check your site's security.